# How to refresh resource from Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, resources, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have changed some resource. When I click on it in Eclipse I get info "Resource is out of sync". How can I refresh it? I tried `org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.touch(IProgressMonitor)`, but it does not help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an `IResource` for the changed resource/project, you might want to [call refreshLocal](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_should_I_use_refreshLocal%3F) on it. However, if you did the modifications programmatically yourself (e.g. through `java.io`), you might want to change your code to do the modifications using the Eclipse IResource API, so that Eclipse can keep track of the modifications itself.

**Update** to elaborate on the Eclipse API:

Instead of e.g. creating a new `FileOutputStream` by specifying the file-path, your plugin should create the file (a resource) using the Eclipse API, e.g. by calling project.create("file") relative to the current project (you can easily for example obtain the currently selected file or project in the Eclipse project explorer).

Comment: thx, a lot. it works great. What do you mean by IResource API? Do you mean to somehow get IDocument and change it like that? I used java.io, because it was faster to write.